# Swift - How to optimize cropping of an image

Tags: ios, image, optimization, swift, uiscrollview

I've got an image, which is generated programmatically, it's a bit wider than iPhone's screen.
Also I have a ScrollView and I want to create something like parallax when it's scrolling.
But I faced optimization problem on my iPhone 4S and I don't know what am I doing wrong.
I mean, if I can zoom any photo in Gallery and scroll it smoothly, why can't I do the same in my program?

That's what I'm doing when ScrollView is scrolled:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollview: UIScrollView) {
    // Get image offset
    var pageSize: Float = Float(scrollView.bounds.size.width)
    var page: Float = floorf((Float(scrollview.contentOffset.x) - pageSize / 2.0) / pageSize) + 1

    if (page >= Float(levelPagesCount)) {
        page = Float(levelPagesCount) - 1;
    }
    else if (page < 0) {
        page = 0;
    }
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)

    var dx = scrollview.contentOffset.x

    // When we know offset - we can crop an image and get necessary part of it
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    var cgimg: CGImageRef?
    var drawn = false

    // Crop an image in another thread
    queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
        if(!self.locked) {
            self.locked = true
            cgimg = self.imageClass!.getImage(dx)
            drawn = true
        }

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
            if(drawn) {
                self.myImageView!.layer.contents = cgimg
                self.locked = false
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

And that's how I crop an image

```
public func getImage(xOffset: CGFloat) -> CGImage {
    // Here 'img' is my wide image
    return CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(img, CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight))!
}
```

I don't know, may be there are another ways to do that, may be I make a horrible mistake, which causes loss of performance. Please, help me.